# Paste multiple times

Tags: vim, copy, paste

What is the best way replace multiple lines with the contents of the clipboard?

The problem I'm having is when I yank a line and paste it over another line the "yank" is replaced with the line I just replace. Now, if I want to replace another line with the same line I have to go back up and yank it again.

There's got to be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I have this in my `.vimrc`:

```
xnoremap p pgvy
```

(note: this will work only with the default register, but this mapping is easy to remember). Writing a more elaborate version would be possible.

Also, you can press <kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>) instead of <kbd>p</kbd> to paste over the selection without overwriting the clipboard.

Comment: Clever. 'p' to paste, 'gv' to re-select what was originally selected. 'y' to copy it again.

Comment: @SibbsGambling, probably using a version prior to Vim 7? Then either upgrade Vim, or use v instead of x (`vnoremap`). Vim help file `version7.txt` states xmap and smap appeared in that version.

Comment: @Benoit Hmm, I have 7.4.52, but neither `xnoremap` nor `vnoremap` works

Comment: Why isn't this the default behavior??

Comment: Please note that this remapping has one issue though : if you are replacing a shorter text by a longer one, the second time you paste, it will have stored a shorter text. https://i.imgur.com/Nehm7fL.mp4

Answer (score 33):

`"0` should have the contents of your yank. It's a bit more tedious to type, but `"0p` should do what you want.

Alternatively, don't select-and-replace the old lines up front.  If you find those lines with a search, just hit `n.` over and over (after an initial `p`), then when they're all pasted, do `ndd` followed by as many `n.`s as necessary.

The biggest mental switch I've needed to make when moving to Vim is to figure out how to apply group edits sequentially.  I.e. rather than doing a bunch of edits on a line and then doing a bunch of the same edits on another line, I'll do the first edit on a bunch of lines (using `.` to great effect), then the second edit on a bunch of lines, etc.  Alternatively, the use of macros may help as they are fantastic, but sometimes a little more tedious to get working correctly with "complex" changes.

Comment: sounds like a place where regex with confirm `:%s/.../.../gc` type commands might be closer to what you want

Comment: @Milimetric +1 didn't know you could confirm like that.

Comment: Upvoting because macros can make this a non-issue.  Just make the edit once, and you can do something like `5@m` (for a macro named `m`)

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. Now I use `xnoremap p "0p` in my ~/.vimrc

Answer (score 16):

I often use another registry, copy the line you need to some named registry `"ay` and then paste from there `"ap`

Answer (score 14):

When you paste over a selection in Vim it will replace the default register with the contents of the selection.  If pasting over a selection is wiping out the contents of the clipboard register then very likely you have the following line in your .vimrc

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

One option is to remove that and use the explicit clipboard register `"+`

Another option is to use any of the other explicitly named registers (a-z).  After the first paste yank the line back into `"c` for example and then use `"cp` to paste from there on out.

Comment: Actually the default (here, on Ubuntu) was clipboard=autoselect; still, thanks for the most elegant answer so far.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of using copy/paste, it is often better to use a text object command such as `ciw` to change the inner word. This method has the advantage of being easily repeatable using the `.` repeat command.

1. `yiw`    Yank inner word (copy word under cursor, say "first").
2. ...  Move the cursor to another word (say "second").
3. `ciw<C-r>0`  Change "second", replacing it with "first" ( is Ctrl-R).
4. ...  Move the cursor to another word (say "third").
5. `.`  Change "third", replacing it with "first".

Comment: `ciw<C-r>0` does not work in my case. `ciw` changes to the insert mode where `<C-r>` becomes useless. Ist there an easy explanation for this? Could that have to do with the texteditor (I am  not using pur VIM but VIM Keyboard bindings in RStudio)

Comment: @Bushroot `<C-r>` is intended to be used in insert mode, as it's how you paste from a register without leaving insert mode—in Vim, that is; I'm not familiar with RStudio but I'd guess that you're right and they haven't implemented this particular key binding.

Comment: @Sean H: Yes. They did not implement the key binding. It work fine in VIM and even with VIM bindings in other programmes (e.g. Visual Studio Code).

Answer (score 8):

use `np` where `n` is the number of how much time you want to paste the lines eg `3p` will paste 3 lines.

Comment: Doesn't work when you want to paste the same line over non-contiguous lines.

Comment: @Tobu but it does answer the title of this question 'how do you paste multiple times'

Answer (score 5):

Use `P` instead of `p`.

`p` will paste from the unnamed register (") and replace its contents with the deleted text.

`P` will keep pasting from the unnamed register (") without replacing its contents with the deleted text.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer nowadays in my opinion. Works out of the box withouth having to remap or anything.

Answer (score 2):

Add below key mapping, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to paste.

```
" Paste Register 0  
map <C-p> "0p
```

Comment: Simple and effective.